# Multi docker containers on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, How to scale each container?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, docker, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I plan to use ElasticBeanstalk docker runtime.
We plan to construct a multi container that launches Laravel application container and Laravel queue worker container.
There is no problem deploying them.

However, there is a doubt about how they scales.
For example, if only the load of the Laravel application container increases, only that container increases and the queue worker container does not increase?
Or does the two containers increase in the same way in any case?

I want the former to be like.

If you have knowledge, tell me.
Thanks for reading.